# Draw a line with mixed color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw `geom_line` with mixed colors used for each line. For example, the lines are drawn in red when the `y` value is over 0.5 and in blue otherwise. The following is a nasty sketch:

[image: a nasty sketch]

Clearly, we can draw different line segments separately (2 blue segments and 1 red segments). But I still wonder whether we can achieve this in a more convenient way.

*Note*, I have tried to add a third variable to indicate the color, and supplied that variable to `aes()`. However, it ended up with something like the figure below,

[image: wrong figure]

where the segments of the same color is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify a single `group` so that a single line will be drawn

```
d = transform(data.frame(x = 1:10, y = c(6:10, 10:6)), col = y > 7)
graphics.off()
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, color = col, group = 1)) +
    geom_line(size = 2)
```

Comment: Looks like an elegant solution! Glad to learn this trick in ggplot2. Btw, does it means that the ggplot2 aesthetic function automatically sets the group to the same as the color, if no group is supplied?